Как получить упрощенный объект с помощью TS дженериков?
Все привет, помогите разобраться с дженериками в typescript.
Есть вот такой объект, ключи имен group могут быть любыми, ключи имен variant тоже могут быть любыми:
const bigUser = {
    group1: {
        variant1: {
            title: 'Egor',
            age: 26,
        },
        variant2: {
            title: 'Sasha',
            age: 29,
        }
    },
    group2: {
        variant1: {
            title: 'Ivan',
            age: 33,
        },
        variant2: {
            title: 'Igor',
            age: 37,
        }
    }
};

Хочу на выходе получить вот такой объект
const miniUser = {
    group1: {
        variant1: 'Egor',
        variant2: 'Sasha'
    },
    group2: {
        variant1: 'Ivan',
        variant2: 'Igor'
    }
};

Описал вот такую функцию
function getNewObj<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U extends keyof K>(obj: T) {
    const newUser: {[K in keyof T]?: {[U in keyof K]: string}} = {};


    (Object.keys(obj) as K[]).forEach((groupKey) => {
        newUser[groupKey] = {}  as T[K];

        if (obj[groupKey]) {
            (Object.keys(obj[groupKey]) as U[]).forEach((key) => {
                newUser[groupKey]['key'] = obj[groupKey][key].title as T[K][U];
            })
        }
    })

    return newUser;
}

Есть три проблемы, подскажите как их правильно решить

Как описать правильно title в (obj[groupKey][key].title) - Property 'title' does not exist on type 'T[K][U]'

newUser[groupKey]['key'] - Object is possibly 'undefined' и

newUser[groupKey]['key'] - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"key"' can't be used to index type '{ [U in keyof K]: string; }'.   Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ [U in keyof K]: string; }'.


спасибо

Тут нужны дополнительные типы для описания юзера и немного другой подход к дженерикам. Подскажите, group1, group2, variant1, variant2 - это заранее известные ключи, или они каждый раз ожидаются разными?

Ответы на вопросы


Как описать правильно title в (obj[groupKey][key].title) - Property 'title' does not exist on type 'T[K][U]'


Ошибка говорит о том, что title не существует для типа T[K][U]. Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы в качестве T передаете "некий object", который может и не содержать на третьем уровне вложенности поле title. Как исправить эту ошибку - дать obj такой тип, чтобы typescript знал, что T[K][U] - это строгий тип, имеющий поля title: string и age: number.


newUser[groupKey]['key'] - Object is possibly 'undefined
newUser[groupKey]['key'] - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"key"' can't be used to index type '{ [U in keyof K]: string; }'. Property 'key' does not exist on type '{ [U in keyof K]: string; }'.


Здесь вы наверняка имели ввиду следующее: newUser[groupKey][key] (без одинарных кавычек). Но даже решения для вышеперечисленных проблем не решают вашу задачу.

Решение
Все ваши проблемы решаются определением типов для User, Group и Variant. Решение представлено ниже. Итоговая функция возвращает объект типа OutUser, ключи которого тайпскрипт успешно распознает благодаря тому что эти ключи строятся из передаваемого в функцию obj: User и его ключей G и V. Я позволил себе изменить обозначения для generic типов и имена переменных в функции. Сам код функции делает абсолютно тоже самое, что и делал до этого. Ссылка на TS Playground
type User<G extends string, V extends string> =  {[groupKey in G]: Group<V>}; 
type Group<V extends string> = {[variantKey in V]: Variant};
type Variant = {
  title: string;
  age: number;
};
type OutUser<G extends string, V extends string> = {[groupKey in G]: OutGroup<V>};
type OutGroup<V extends string> = {[variantKey in V]: string};

function getNewObj<G extends string, V extends string>(obj: User<G, V>): OutUser<G, V> {
  const newUser = {} as OutUser<G, V>;

  (Object.keys(obj) as G[]).forEach((groupKey) => {
    const group = obj[groupKey];
    const newGroup = {} as OutGroup<V>;
    newUser[groupKey] = newGroup;
    
    if (group) {
      (Object.keys(group) as V[]).forEach((variantKey) => {
        newUser[groupKey][variantKey] = obj[groupKey][variantKey].title;
      })
    }
  });

  return newUser;
}

const bigUser = {
  group1: {
      variant1: {
        title: 'Egor',
        age: 26,
      },
      variant2: {
        title: 'Sasha',
        age: 29,
      }
  },
  group2: {
    variant1: {
      title: 'Ivan',
      age: 33,
    },
    variant2: {
      title: 'Igor',
      age: 37,
    }
  }
};
const smallUser = getNewObj(bigUser);
console.log(smallUser);
console.log('smallUser.group1.variant2', smallUser.group1.variant2);

Результат выполнения кода:
[LOG]: {
  "group1": {
    "variant1": "Egor",
    "variant2": "Sasha"
  },
  "group2": {
    "variant1": "Ivan",
    "variant2": "Igor"
  }
} 
[LOG]: "smallUser.group1.variant2",  "Sasha" 

