Проверка типа объекта при конвертировании из другого типа в TS
Помогите решить задачу.
Пишу функцию конвертер, которая принимает объект и должна его конвертировать в другой объект.
Делаю это так:
const converter = <T extends object, R>(obj: T): R => {
  return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj)?.map(([k, v])=> {
    if (k === 'type') {
      return {[k]: v.toString()}
    }
  }))
}

Пример сильно упрощён, но Object.assign возвращает объект any, а как мне проверить, что возвращаемый объект соответствует типу R? Функция используется рекурсивно.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1576431/2659, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1575465/2659

Очень странный способ конвертировать объект в другой объект. Нужно больше конкретики о том, какого поведения вы пытаетесь добиться. Дайте хотя бы 2 примера что на входе - что на выходе, и проясните правила конвертации
